# Lee's Proof of Seifert–Van Kampen

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I do not understand a particular step in [Lee's proof](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441979391)  of the Seifert–Van Kampen theorem. We have $X$ the topological space, and loops $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^k$ based at a given $p\in X$, such that $a_1\cdot a_2\cdots  a_{k-1}\cdot a_k\sim c_p,$ where $c_p$ is the constant loop at $p$. Divide the unit interval into $n$ segments. Now, Lee asserts that

"by taking $n$ to be a sufficiently large power of $2$, we can ensure that the endpoints of the paths $a_i$ in this product are of the form $i/n".$

But aren't the endpoints of each $a_i\ p$ since $a_i$ is a loop based at $p$?

I thought perhaps that Lee means that one can chop up the path $a_1\cdot a_2\cdots  a_{k-1}\cdot a_k$ in a possibly different way by taking the linear map $k_i$ from $I$ to $[i-1/n,i/n]$ followed by $f:=a_1\cdot a_2\cdots  a_{k-1}\cdot a_k$, but this approach did not work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Lee's proof is too mathematically rigorous and detailed to understand... I recommend reading Hatchers proof and then continuously telling yourself that the result is obvious until you believe it

Comment: Yes, I agree that the proofs should be "intuitive" but I am self-studying this material and I want to understand these things rigorously before I let the pictures do the talking. I've read parts of Hatcher's book and I find some of his hand-waving off-putting. On the other hand, his proof of excision in singular homology is rigorous and crystal-clear. I have read several of Lee's books and they are real gems for self-study in that one is forced to do exercises to complete proofs.

Comment: yeah I was joking i'm not a fan of Hatcher's book

Comment: Sorry, that was a poor use of language on my part. That should have said "the paths $a_i$ in this product are defined on subintervals whose endpoints are integral
multiples of $1/n$.” I've added a correction to my [online list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ITM/).

Comment: And for [a long list of math books errata see here](http://mathbookserrata.wikidot.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something doesn't convince me, if $k$ is arbitrary: if $\alpha_i(1)$ corresponds to $i/n$, then $\alpha_k(1)$ corresponds to $k/n$, and that should be $1$.

Here is a different interpretation.

Path composition $\alpha \cdot \beta$ means you travel through each path at half the unitary speed. So, in $a_1\cdot a_2\cdots  a_{k-1}\cdot a_k$, you travel through the first path at $2^{-1}$ the unitary speed, through the second at $2^{-2}$ the normal speed and so on.

Thus, at $t=2^{-1}$ you reach $\alpha_1(1)$, at $t=2^{-1}+2^{-2}$ you reach $\alpha_2(1)$ and so on. By doing some common denominators you can rewrite that every endpoint $\alpha_i(1)$ corresponds to $b_i/n$, where $b_i$ is some integer and $n=2^{k}$.

Comment: Nice, Thank you. I guess you might have to reparameterize these paths to begin with because $n$ has to satisfy another condition -that of the Lebesgue number $\delta$ for a certain cover. But if $k$ is fixed, we can always choose $n,l$ such that $n=2^{kl}$ and $1/n<\delta.$